# Problema com tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

estou tentando fazer um site de séries, só que estou sofrendo para acertar a lógica das tabelas, primeiro vou explicar como quero que funcione, a pessoa entra no site, ai tem as séries que puxa as seguintes informações do banco `id(int), id_temp(int, id_temporada), nome_serie, lancamento, audio, thumb_serie` até ai tudo bem, ai o meu link que da acesso a série escolhida está assim `<a href="seriado.php?id=1&id_temp=1">Ver Série</a>`, ai na página `seriado.php` eu criei mais duas tabelas no banco, que são `episodios` e `temporadas`, na tabela `episodios` tenho os seguintes campos `id(int), id_temp(int), nome_episodio, sinopse, link_video` e na tabela `temporadas` tenho os seguintes campos `id(int), id_temp(int), nome_temporada(int)`

os meus `select` estão assim `(series) select * from series`, `(episodios) select * from episodios where id = $id or id_temp = $id_temp`, `(temporadas) select * from temporadas where id = $id or id_temp = $id_temp` [image: index.php][image: seriado.php]

Comment: Você quer pegar os filmes relacionados a uma série? Por exemplo, se acessar uma série chamada "A procura do PHP" listar os episódios dessa série?

Comment: sim, os espisodios e temporadas

Comment: Certo, na tabela, esses episódios tem uma relação com a série, no caso uma foreign key, ou algo que diga que este episódio pertence a tal série?

Comment: eu usei o `id_temp`  pra isso, editei a pergunta, acho que ficou melhor oque eu tentei fazer, e oque eu espero

Answer (score 1):

Melhor Normalizar o banco da seguinte maneira:

**Tabela Series**    : IDSerie Nome

Como o espisódio é da temporada, logo:

**Tabela Temporadas:** IDTemporada, IDSerie(FK)

O episódio é ligado a temporada, logo:

**Tabela Episodios**: IDEpisodios, IDTemporada(FK)

Assim se quiser selecionar poderia usar os innerJoins exemplo:

Select s.* from series as s inner join temporadas t ON s.IDSerie = t.IDSerie left join Episodios E on t.IDTemporada = e.IDTemporada.

Usei o left join no final devido a possibilidade de existir series com temporada mas sem episodios ainda.

Essa é uma forma de fazer.

Comment: desculpa mano, oque significa `FK` ?

Comment: Foreing key  - chave estrangeira. Cada tabela tem uma chave unica (primary key). Quando elas são usadas em outras tabelas para relacionamentos, elas mudam de nome e sao chamada de foreing key (fk)  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp